# Problema conexión Django + Firebird

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, firebird

Estimados, quiero conectar django con dos bases de datos y me ecuentro con el problema que cuando ejecuto el comando:

> python manage.py inspectdb

para ver si esta todo en orden, me muestra este este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django_firebird-1.9a0-py3.5.egg\firebird\base.py", line 154, in get_new_con
nection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 736, in connect
    return connection_class(_db_handle, dpb, sql_dialect, charset, isolation_lev
el)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 963, in __init__
    verstr = self.db_info(isc_info_firebird_version)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 1439, in db_info
    buf = self.database_info(infoCode, 's')
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 1327, in database_info
    raise InternalError("Result code does not match request code.")
fdb.fbcore.InternalError: Result code does not match request code.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line

    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 25, in handle
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 38, in handle_inspectio
n
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\utils\six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\django_firebird-1.9a0-py3.5.egg\firebird\base.py", line 154, in get_new_con
nection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 736, in connect
    return connection_class(_db_handle, dpb, sql_dialect, charset, isolation_lev
el)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 963, in __init__
    verstr = self.db_info(isc_info_firebird_version)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 1439, in db_info
    buf = self.database_info(infoCode, 's')
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 1327, in database_info
    raise InternalError("Result code does not match request code.")
django.db.utils.InternalError: Result code does not match request code.
```

Tengo instalado lo siguiente:

```
cheroot==5.5.0
cherrypy==10.2.2
cx-Freeze==5.0.1
Django==1.8
django-firebird==1.9a0
fdb==1.7
future==0.16.0
mysqlclient==1.3.10
pefile==2016.3.28
portend==1.8
py2exe==0.9.2.2
pyinstaller==3.2.1
pymysql==0.7.11
pyodbc==4.0.16
pypiwin32==219
pytz==2017.2
pywin32==221
six==1.10.0
tempora==1.6.1
urllib3==1.21.1
```

No puedo encontrar la solución para este error. Recorrí todos los foros, instale distintas versiones de python... pero siempre llego al mismo error.

> File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pack
>       ages\fdb-1.7-py3.5.egg\fdb\fbcore.py", line 1327, in database_info
>           raise InternalError("Result code does not match request code.")
>       django.db.utils.InternalError: Result code does not match request code.

El archivo ***settings.py*** tiene los siguiente:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'mysql', # Path to database or db alias
        'USER' : 'mysqluser',           # Your db user
        'PASSWORD' : '*********',    # db user password
        'HOST' : 'mihost.com',        # Your host machine
        'PORT' : '3306',             # If is empty, use default 3050
        #'OPTIONS' : {'charset':'ISO8859_1'}
    },

    'firebird': {
        'ENGINE' : 'firebird',
        'NAME' : 'firebird.GDB', # Path to database or db alias
        'USER' : 'SYSDBA',           # Your db user
        'PASSWORD' : '*******',    # db user password
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',        # Your host machine
        'PORT' : '3050',             # If is empty, use default 3050
        'OPTIONS' : {'charset':'ISO8859_1'}
    }


}
```

> El problema es con ***Firebird***. Si coloco únicamente la
>   base de datos de ***Mysql*** funciona.

Comment: Es un problema exclusivo del driver, no relacionado con Django. Asegúrate que puedes conectarse a FireBird desde Python.

Comment: @toledano - Cambie de versión de django y firebird (django==1.2;Kinterbasdb==3.3), tuve que bajar de versión e instalar kinterbase, por que estoy asumiendo que puede ser problema de driver. Pero sigue con el problema de no reconocerme la librería Firebird. Este es el error que me muestra:`Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named firebird.base`

Comment: Has intentado poner el path completo de la BD en la propiedad 'NAME' : '/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/django_firebird.fdb', # Path to database or db alias

Comment: @softMolina si esta completo el path, pero ahora me muestra otro error...   `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_firebird-1.4.5-py2.7.egg\firebird\operations.py", line 22, in _get_firebird_version
    return [int(val) for val in server_version.split()[-1].split('.')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'WI-V6''` . Espero que no sea un problema de versiones con el servidor.**Estoy usando Interbase,Firebird 1.X y Kinterbasdb(python-django)**

Comment: Pero este ya es otro tipo de error en tu código ya no de la conexión a tu base de datos, dada su rastreo el problema es obvio. int() se lleva a números enteros y están tratando de darle un decimal, por lo que es necesario utilizar float().

Comment: la extension de firebird es gdb????